# Cant delete file in Android

Tags: java, android, file, video, internal-storage

## Problem :

I want to delete video file from android device's internal storage.

> Below code is in class that extends BaseAdapter and "file.delete()" method  returns false

```java
    File fdelete = new File(videolist.get(position).getVideopath());
                        Log.d(TAG,"Path to delete : "+videolist.get(position).getVideopath());
                        if (fdelete.exists()) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"DELETE EXIST");
                            if (fdelete.delete()) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"DELETED");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG,"NOT DELETED");
                            }
                        }
```

> " videolist.get(position).getVideopath() "  returns this : "/storage/emulated/0/Download/jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264xgdhdudtudutdutdjtditditdtidjtditdjtdtkd.mkv"

Comment: Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? Did you request it at runtime using `requestPermissions()`?

Comment: Yes I did.I am doing other operations like getting video files from internal storage.And that works normal.

Comment: Is the file actually being deleted? IOW, if you use Device Explorer in Android Studio, or `adb shell`, to look at this directory, is the file gone after the `delete()` call?

Comment: I checked device storage video file  not deleted.

Comment: I edited question that code snipped is in the class that extends BaseAdapter

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    private void deleteMedia(final String advName) {
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/your directory name");

    File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.contains(advName);
        }
    });
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How I pass value to advname   " sad.txt " or just " sad "

Comment: Only text  "sad"

Comment: Its not working.I checked file path in " for "  loop.Its like : " /storage/emulated/0/Download/asd.txt " . But  " file.delete() " not working.